# Custom Button to mass update records

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to know whether it is possible to put a custom button say 
"Convert All" in the following view along with "New Merchandise", "Change Owner" buttons.

[image]

This custom button would act on all selected records.

The problem statement is to allow the user to perform mass update/delete in UI itself.

If creating a custom button to perform mass update on records is not possible, then can someone let me know what is the best solution for this ?.

Comment: Not sure about a custom button, but this prototype might help you get started: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_massupdate.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@UnderDog, what you're describing can most easily be implemented as a **custom button** that invokes JavaScript. Take a look at Salesforce Help's [sample Mass Delete](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=links_useful_custom_buttons_mass_delete.htm&language=en_US) button, and from there I believe you can adapt the sample to both do a mass convert and mass delete for Merchandise records in your org. For a more complete reference on everything you can do via JavaScript, I recommend reading the [*AJAX Toolkit  Developer's Guide*](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/).

Comment: This no longer applies for Lightning, because JavaScript cannot be used.  Does anyone know how to do this in Lightning?

Comment: @Mr.B good point, and I think your question sounds like it'd make a great new post here on Stack Exchange.